# ModelChoiceField: get only objects used as a Foreign Key in another object

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two classes:

```
class Nationality(Model):
    name = models.Charfield()

class Person(Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    nationality = ForeignKey("Nationality")
```

I want to display, in a `ModelChoiceField` in an altogether different form, only those nationalities that are used as a foreign key in the `Person` table. There are actually many more, but I'm only interested in those that are used as a foreign key to an existing `Person`.

This *doesn't* work, as it returns a dict with the fieldname and referenced primary key.

```
Person.objects.values('nationality')
```

I want the `Nationality` object to be returned so I am able to reference its `name` attribute.

I don't want to use raw SQL, as my model's further complicated by a multilingual module.

Answer (score 2):

You can use annotations to filter those nationalities that have at least one Person.

```
from django.db.models import Count
Nationality.objects.annotate(person_count=Count('person')).filter(person_count__gte=1)
```

Comment: That worked! Due to what magic, I don't know, but it certainly worked. I mean how does `Count` know about the `person` as the relationship is based in the `Person`? I guess I have to do some reading on Aggregations! Many thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, aggregation docs are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/aggregation/), but be sure to also read up on [backwards relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) if you don't already know about that.